# The real story of two mischievous brothers

Tags: riddle, story, history

> Once upon a time there was a woman named Alice. She had two husbands, Mr. Cantor and Alex.
>
> From Mr. Cantor, she had a son. He was very mischievous. All people in the house were bothered by him. But his fun-time ended with time.
>
> After some years, she had another son from Alex. He was even more mischievous than his brother. So of course, people in the home were even more bothered by him. Once he called his friends, Phat and Stuart at home. They destroyed all the thing in a whole room. Younger son and the whole family felt bad for his destructed room. Hearing so much sound, their landlord Yun Ong came to their home and told the whole family to not call such a devilry kids at home.

What does this story reminds you of? Answer should have all characters explained.

Note: If you think that characters in the story were real human beings then I would like to say 'LOL NO'

Hint 1 :

> Added a tag and changed the name from Ally to Alice.

Findings of our peers:

> 1. "(Phat) Fat Boy" and "(Stuart) Little Boy" nukes were dropped on Japan." (found by Doug.McFarlane)
> 2. Yun Ong: United Nations. (found by karobar)
>  I think that the way in which United Nations is named Yun Ong should give you some hint how other names are assigned.

Comment: Are these perhaps cats?

Comment: @Gamow no...none of the characters share any resemblance to any living or dead being. Any resemblance would be purely coincidental.

Comment: Are these from a fairy tale or a cartoon o.O

Comment: @ABcDexter no...and sorry for the other day...i had to delete the question bcz of a bad response.

Comment: It's ok, hope read liked my answer.

Comment: Geographical features, by any chance?

Comment: @thokiro nope...

Comment: describing a country's history maybe?

Comment: @vefthym yeah...sort of..

Comment: Was Alice married to Mr. Cantor concurrently with her marriage to Alex? Or was Mr. Cantor Alice's first husband, and Alex her second?

Comment: @question_asker Mr. Cantor was the first husband...and Alex was the second...

Comment: "(Phat) Fat Boy" and "(Stuart) Little Boy" nukes were dropped on Japan?

Comment: Are you sure that [history] is the right tag? The tag info says it's only related to the history of puzzles.

Comment: @karobar the 'historical' tag directly converted into 'history' tag. So take the question as historical until this confusion is solved on meta...

Comment: @Doug.McFarlane you are too close now..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alice

> **Allied Powers/Allies of World War I and World War II** This link was just based on phonetics and context of the rest of the puzzle

Mr. Cantor

> **Central Powers:** *[husband of Alice]* Opponent of the Allies.

Alice and Cantor's son

> **World War I:** *From Mr. Cantor, she had a son. He was very mischievous. All people in the house were bothered by him. But his fun-time ended with time.* A war between the Central Powers and the Allies, where there was a great loss of lives and resources. The war involved the entire world, but the war eventually ended.

Alex

> **Axis Powers:** *[husband of Alice]* Opponent of the Allies.

Alice and Alex's son

> **World War II:** *After some years, she had another son from Alex. He was even more mischievous than his brother. So of course, people in the home were even more bothered by him.*  World War II had a greater toll on lives and economies than WWI, which set an uneasiness in the global zeitgeist.

Phat & Stuart

> **Fat Man & Little Boy:** *Once he called his friends, Phat and Stuart at home.* Like the atomic bombings of Hiroshima and Nagasaki. Stuart Little links to Little Boy.

Yun Ong

> **United Nations:** *Hearing so much sound, their landlord Yun Ong came to their home and told the whole family to not call such a devilry kids at home.* This could be analogous to the signing of the Treaty on the Non-Proliferation of Nuclear Weapons by the UN in 1968

Comment: Will do ASAP.  great puzzle! The Mr. Cantor/Alex thing took me ages

Comment: nice answer. I had figured out the rest except Mr. Cantor and Alex, since husbands is not maybe the most suitable metaphor for that kind of relationship :)